# Adding advertising in the application?

Tags: java, android, xml

I am using this code:

```
 <com.google.android.gms.ads.AdView android:id="@+id/adView"
   android:layout_width="wrap_content"
   android:layout_height="wrap_content"
   ads:adUnitId="MY_AD_UNIT_ID"
   ads:adSize="BANNER"/>
```

But is in error :

> ```
> Description Resource Path Location Type error: No resource identifier
>   found for attribute 'loadAdOnCreate' in package 'com.teste.teste1'
>   activity_teste.xml /Teste/res/layout line 120 Android AAPT Problem
> ```

Answer (score 0):

You need to add your unique ad unit id. To get this you need to create a new banner ad in your [AdMob](https://apps.admob.com) profile after you set up a new application for monetization.

**EDIT:**
Remove "loadAdOnCreate" attribute on the 120th line since it can not be used as XML attribute.

**EDIT 2:**
Possible new solutions:

- Add `xmlns:ads="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto` to your parentl ayout in XML.
- Add Google Play services to your dependencies:

> compile 'com.google.android.gms:play-services:6.+'

- Add a meta tag in your application's manifest:

> ```
>     <!--This meta-data tag is required to use Google Play Services.-->
>     <meta-data android:name="com.google.android.gms.version"
>             android:value="@integer/google_play_services_version" />
> ```

- Add config changes and theme for adactivity in your application's manifest:

> ```
> <!--Include the AdActivity configChanges and theme. -->
>     <activity android:name="com.google.android.gms.ads.AdActivity"
>         android:configChanges="keyboard|keyboardHidden|orientation|screenLayout|uiMode|screenSize|smallestScreenSize"
>         android:theme="@android:style/Theme.Translucent" />
> ```

Comment: well removed , and the error go out, but did not show banner

Comment: @Rodolfo post your code on how you build your ad request.

Comment: ` AdView adView = (AdView)this.findViewById(R.id.adView);
        AdRequest adRequest = new AdRequest.Builder().build();
        adView.loadAd(adRequest);`

Comment: @Rodolfo This should have worked, what does your logcat when adrequest builds an ad?

Comment: Graphical Layout in the following message appears in the Banner XML Required attribute " adSize " was missing .

Comment: @Rodolfo I suggest you to start over again and check all the steps, see the article: https://developers.google.com/mobile-ads-sdk/docs/admob/android/quick-start

Comment: @Rodolfo Or provide more informations so we can help you out.

Comment: not endetendi to where I lay compile 'com.google.android.gms:play-services:6.+'